# jquery animate opacity to 1.0 the text abruptly goes back to original state

Tags: jquery

I made up an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6P6Rq/

I'm using the latest version of chrome. So basically when the text fades back to full opacity it kind of switches back to its original text appearance. I tried doing 0.999 opacity instead of 1, however it doesn't have the same appearance as text that is at 1.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not seeing this problem in Chrome.

Comment: I dont understand your question, can you clarify

Comment: are you saying the fade in chrome does not behave exactly like the fade in FF? It seems like an almost instantly bolds the text when it fades back to full opacity. I think this is just normal behavior of the browser

Comment: I dont understand your problem

Comment: I believe this is a Mac only issue. I check the same thing on windows and the fade works perfectly. The OP must be on a mac, when fading back in, it does look weird

Comment: yes Huan I'm on osx. That's exactly what I'm talking about, it looks as if it is being bolded at the end of the animation. Even in IE8 on my virtual machine it shows some issues. Hover over and off and compare the link to the other links. It doesn't have anti-aliasing anymore I think

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem on Osx Chrome. I'm fading in some text that is not even supposed to be bold, in fact it has a font-weight of 100, yet when it fades in Chrome snaps it into bold in the last frame, having the same appearance as your jsfiddle example. The animation works on all other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem stems from how chrome chooses to render it's font opacity changes. FF and IE don't seem to have the same sort of problems but I do notice the sudden skip as it fills in the width of the font at the end of the fading animation.

I tried using:

```
a { opacity: 1; -webkit-transition: 0.5s;  }
a:hover{ opacity: 0.3; -webkit-transition: 0.5s; }
```

but it still presented the same "snapping" at the end. That's really unfortunate.

Changing the speed of the fade to be a little quicker makes the sudden change seem less abrupt but that's all that I've been able to come up with, since all other methods seem to generate the same end result.